# Multiple Worksheet_Change events in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge two Worksheet_Change events.

The aim of the code is to convert any uppercase text in the cell ranges given to lowercase.

I tried copying both into the same `Worksheet_Change`, but Excel crashed.

Range 1:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ccr As Range
    Set ccr = Range("C6")
    For Each Cell In ccr
    Cell.Value = LCase(Cell)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Range 2:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim acr As Range
    Set acr = Range("C9:G9")
    For Each Cell In acr
    Cell.Value = LCase(Cell)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just put the code in one event then.

Comment: The answers provided are all good except that they have no error handling.  So if your code fails between the "Application.EnableEvents = False" and the "Application.EnableEvents = True" statements, then you just left Excel is a bad state where no events will fire.  Any time you use "Application.EnableEvents", "Application.ScreenUpdating", etc. always use error handling to make sure that if your code fails, those kind of settings get set back to what they need to be.  I'm a .NET/C# developer (VBA = Megablocks, C#=Lego Technic) and error handling is a must.

Comment: @FrankBall Right, added one in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this you can do both the things in same event

You have to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the starting to avoid race condition.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ccr As Range, acr as Range

    Set ccr = Range("C6")
    For Each Cell In ccr
      Cell.Value = LCase(Cell)
    Next Cell

    Set acr = Range("C9:G9")
    For Each Cell In acr
      Cell.Value = LCase(Cell)
    Next Cell
 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes it

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is that changing a cell value `Cell.Value` will trigger another `Worksheet_Change` immediately. You need to `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent this.

Also I recommend to work with `Intersect` so the code only runs on the cells that are actually changed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("C6, C9:G9"))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'pervent triggering another change event

        Dim Cel As Range
        For Each Cel In AffectedRange.Cells
            Cel.Value = LCase$(Cel.Value)
        Next Cel

        Application.EnableEvents = True 'don't forget to re-enable events in the end
    End If
End Sub
```

---

In addition to @Frank Ball's comment including error handling:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("C6, C9:G9"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False 'pervent triggering another change event
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLING

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cel As Range
        For Each Cel In AffectedRange.Cells
            Cel.Value = LCase$(Cel.Value)
        Next Cel
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'no Exit Sub here!
ERR_HANDLING:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The two `Worksheet_Change` events are quite the same, they are a loop around a range, returning `LCase()`. Thus, it is a good idea to make a separate Sub for it like this:

```
Sub FixRangeLCase(rangeToFix As Range)        
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In rangeToFix
        myCell.Value2 = LCase(myCell.Value2)
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

Then, refer the Worksheet_Change event to it. As far as the `Worksheet_Change` event is quite "expensive", running always, it is a good idea to run it only when a specific Target cell is changed and otherwise exit the procedure -     `If Intersect(Target, Range("C6"), Range("C9:G9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

The `Application.EnableEvents = False` is needed to disable the events. At the end it is set back to `True`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6"), Range("C9:G9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    FixRangeLCase Range("C6")
    FixRangeLCase Range("C9:G9")
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9:G9")) Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Range("C9:G9", "C6")

            For Each cell In rng
                cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
            Next
        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not right because it only changes target cell

Comment: This `Target.Value = LCase(Target.Value)` fails if `Target` is a range of multiple cells. `LCase` cannot handle an array of values `Target.Value`.

Comment: @newguy what you mention is not an issue here because only `Target` cells actually changed so the others are already lower case (and don't need to be converted again). •  The issue here would be that it would run on **all** changed cells even outside the given range not only on the cells in `C6, C9:G9` (but actually it fails because of the reason I mentioned above).

Comment: @Error When using the `Worksheet_Change` event always keep in mind that `Target` can be a pasted `Range` not only a singe cell.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i believe i get the point & i have edit the answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @newguy answer edited. any other suggestions or corrections are welcome!

Comment: Better in the meaning of not crashing because of `Target` beeing a range. But note that if eg only cell C10 is edited the complete `rng` is converted to lower case while only C10 changed and it would be sufficient to convert this cell only. To prevent this see my answer where I used `AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("C6, C9:G9"))` to get only the changed cells of the desired range. So you would end up with what I answered.

Comment: What is .parent use for?

Comment: If the event is triggered while another worksheet has focus I'm not sure to which worksheet `Range` would default `Target.Parent` gives the worksheet where the range `Target` is in. So this ensures that `Range("C6, C9:G9")` points to the same worksheet as `Target` points to. Just to be save and not let Excel decide which sheet I mean.